# String join in select object or Export-Csv

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I line that export all 365 users to a CSV:

```
Get-MsolUser |
    Select-Object -Property UserPrincipalName, DisplayName, Licenses,
        LastLogonTime, Country, IsLicensed, UsageLocation, UserType |
    Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\365-users.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

`Licenses` is an array of objects. Each object in the array have a property `AccountSkuId`. Is it possible in the oneliner above to join the array into a comma separated string? Right now it returns following:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Online.Administration.UserLicense]
```

Notice I want to keep the License in the header, so my best bet would be it is in the export part. Or do I need to make a `for` loop and do it manually?

Comment: Try using a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx): `Select-Object ..., @{n='Licenses';e={($_.Licenses | Select-Object -Expand AccountSkuId) -join ';'}}, ...`.

Comment: Also, are you using PowerShell v2 or PowerShell v3? The latter has new features that simplify handling this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build on @Ansgar's suggestion, here is how you would integrate a calculated property into your present select statement and retrieve the properties you're looking for.

```
Select-Object -Property UserPrincipalName, DisplayName, `
  @{name="licenses";expression={$_.licenses.accountskuid -join ";"}}, `
  LastLogonTime, Country, IsLicensed, UsageLocation, UserType |
    Export-Csv -Path c:\temp\365-users.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Note that `$_.licenses.accountskuid` requires PowerShell v3 or newer.

Comment: Thanks both. Pretty nifty solution with the name;expression syntax. Highly appreciated. @AnsgarWiechers hope it is OK I answer this, even if you had a big part in this too. It has been tested and works perfectly.